# How to remove duplicate files from an arraylist

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

A bit different from the others. I'm retrieving an arraylist of files for processing (basically handling DLL registration on a local machine), and I need my script to properly handle multiple DLLs with the same name. The `select -Unique` doesn't work, since technically the files aren't duplicates - each has its own unique full path.

I need this script to retrieve all DLLs in a folder (as well as sub-folders), but only return the last instance of each named file. For example if I have files:

- C:\Path\Update1\GRM.DLL
- C:\Path\Update1\HTCP.DLL
- C:\Path\Update2\GRM.DLL
- C:\Path\Update3\GRM.DLL

The script should return the objects for Update3\GRM.DLL and Update1\HTCP.DLL.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$dlls = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object 
{$_.Extension -eq ".dll" -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'dll_Old'})
```

Edit: Got it going with this, but it's selecting the first instance that shows up, and I need the last. In this example, that means it's snagging Update1/GRM.DLL instead of Update3/GRM.DLL

```
$dlls = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".dll" -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'dll_Old'}) | Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: Either use Select-Unique on the leaf (Split-Path -Leaf) or look into the Group-Object cmdlet - depending on how you want to use the output.

Comment: @Scepticalist Thank you! Actually got it going with the updated code, but it's selecting the wrong unique value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hashtable to keep track of the last file seen for a specific file name:

```
$files = @{}

Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -File -Recurse -Filter *.dll |Where-Object FullName -notmatch 'dll_Old' |ForEach-Object {
    $files[$_.Name] = $_
}

$uniqueFiles = $files.Values
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59996170/45375) is probably the best (fastest) solution in this case, but here's an alternative based on the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Filter *.dll |
  Where-Object FullName -notmatch dll_Old |
    Group-Object Name |
      ForEach-Object { $_.Group[-1] }
```

- `Group-Object Name` groups all matching files by their `.Name` property.
- `ForEach-Object { $_.Group[-1] }` then extracts the *last* (`-1`) member from each resulting group.

Note that `Group-Object` will implicitly sort the groups by the grouping property, so the resulting list of file-info objects ([`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo), as output by `Get-ChildItem`) will be sorted by file name.